# Changing Input Element CSS based on Angular Reactive Forms validation

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

**I have a simple reactive form like this:**

```js
this.loginForm = this._fb.group({
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@gmail.com$')]],
  password: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

**The on HTML:**

```html
<!------------------------- PASSWORD FIELD ------------------------->
<div class="uk-margin">
  <input type="password" class="uk-input"
         placeholder="Enter Password" formControlName="password">

  <!----- VALIDATION WARNINGS ----->
  <div *ngIf="loginForm.get('password').touched">
    <div *ngIf="loginForm.get('password').hasError('required')">
      <div class="uk-text-danger"> Password is required.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Then in CSS:**

```css
.ng-valid[required] {
   border: 5px solid #42A948;
 }

.ng-invalid[required] {
   border: 5px solid red; 
 }
```

The `ng-valid/invalid` CSS is being applied. I want to change the colour of the input fields border. But the CSS does not work form me. What am I doing wrong?

Update:

[image]

Comment: `The ng-valid/invalid CSS is being applied - But the CSS does not work for me` I'm getting mixed signals here, is it being applied or not?

Comment: @JeremyThille sorry my English isn't that good. What I mean't was I am adding the `valid/invalid` code in css but its not taking effect. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: The problem is that the HTML code you provided does not match the CSS. There is no `ng-valid` or `ng-invalid` anywhere in the HTML markup

Comment: @JeremyThille Doesn't angular atomically add those classes to the input field? Upon `inspect-element` I can see the `ng-valid, ng-touch` etc classes added into the HTML. Please see my updated question.

Comment: I don't know exactly what Angular does to the classes, and I'm not sure it is relevant. All I can see is that currently, in the HTML code you wrote, nothing matches `.ng-valid[required]` or `.ng-invalid[required]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-invalid and ng-valid are always applied, you can customize css further to resolve this.

```
ng-valid.ng-touched {
  border: 5px solid #42A948;
}

ng-invalid.ng-touched {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Hi actually the form is there. I just didn't post the code as it was quite long. Apologies.

Comment: Removing the `required` makes all the input fields borders coloured.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by enforcing everything immediately?

Comment: @Skywalker, just apply css only if it's been touched

Comment: This worked. Thanks for help! I needed to add the `ng-touched`.

Comment: I would rather recommend using `ngClass` as messing with Angular's classes isn't a really good practice and might take some time to every new guy looking at the project. Also, may not be future-proof :)

Comment: @AhsanAyazm, I disagree, if this impacts a large project, then your project architecture needs to be revised, so the components are partitioned well. We're applying css style here to a single form-based component.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `[ngClass]` for the conditional class based on the error. For example:

```
<!------------------------- PASSWORD FIELD ------------------------->
    <div class="uk-margin">
      <input
        type="password"
        class="uk-input"
        placeholder="Enter Password"
        formControlName="password"
        [ngClass]="{'has-error': loginForm.get('password').touched && loginForm.get('password').hasError('required')}">

      <!----- VALIDATION WARNINGS ----->
      <div *ngIf="loginForm.get('password').touched">
        <div *ngIf="loginForm.get('password').hasError('required')">
          <div class="uk-text-danger"> Password is required.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Then in CSS:

```
uk-input.has-error{
  /* your styles */
}
```